# Increase gap between icon and button java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am doing a program in java in which you have to select a category with a button.

I'm trying to put an icon and text in the JButton, but I can't quite get the alignment right. I want a wider space to the left between the left side of the button and the icon.

I have read that you can create an invisible line border to solve this, but my JButton already has a border.

```
choose_Animals = new JButton ("ANIMALS");
    choose_Animals.setIcon(categoriesIcon[0]);
    choose_Animals.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    choose_Animals.setIconTextGap(20);
    choose_Animals.setOpaque(false);
    choose_Animals.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    choose_Animals.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    choose_Animals.setBorder(border);
    choose_Animals.setFocusable(false);
    choose_Animals.setFont(p);
    choose_Animals.setBounds(90, 220,470, 85);
    choose_Animals.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(choose_Animals);
```

Comment: Don't do this: `choose_Animals.setBounds(90, 220,470, 85);`. Don't use set bounds or null layouts as they are signs of newbie code since this means you don't yet understand the grief that this will lead you to. Learn to use and then do use the layout managers.

Comment: As you said I'm quite a newbie and havent learned to use layout managers yet.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: To use bounds is to make your gui rigid, make it unusable on any system but your own, and make it very difficult to update or enhance. If you move stuff around, then you've got to deal with all the side effects from any move. Study the link above and use the layouts. You won't regret doing this. Also remember to nest JPanels, each using its own layout.

Comment: Thanks for your information about layouts, I'm still learning about them on my own and it will take some time. Do you know if what I ask for is possible with a null layout? If not, which layout do you recommend me to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know if what I ask for is possible with a null layout?

Positioning the text/icon of a button has nothing to do with a layout manager. These are properties of the component itself.

And yes, you should be using a layout manager, not a null layout. The time to learn using layout managers is now, not some time in the future.

> I have read that you can create an invisible line border to solve this,

You can use an `EmptyBorder` to give addition space to one of the 4 inset positions.

> but my JButton already has a border.

You can use a `CompoundBorder` to combing your current Border with the `EmptyBorder`

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, the CompoundBorder solved my questions. Do you know of any place where I can learn to use layouts step by step?

Comment: @LuisdelaCal The [Official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: @LuisdelaCal, `Do you know of any place where I can learn to use layouts ` Sigh...  I gave you a link to a section in the `Swing Tutorial` (on How to Use Borders) with hopes that you would look at the table of contents for other basic Swing information. Take advantage of resources provided to you.